# Meteor Cordova FacebookConnect Plugin: Which method should be called from client side?

Tags: facebook, cordova, meteor

I am using meteor cordova to create an android app. I am using cordova plugin: com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect to enable native android login in my app.

```
facebookConnectPlugin.login(['email'], function(userdata){
      //which server method should be called here?
}, Function failure)
```

I would like to re-use the code. which method should I call to log the user?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the plugin itself takes care of all the mechanism(s) necessary to get the user to provide login information, etc. All you have to do is create a javascript function that fires when the login is successful, or fails.

For instance,

```
facebookConnectPlugin.login(['NeededPermissions'], mySuccessFunction(), myFailureFunction());
```

then have two separate js functions that implement those two functions.

Comment: I understand that. This method does authentication with facebook. I am new to meteor. So I wanted to ask what API should be called to update or insert into user collection on server side.